# ruby : compare two words and extract uncommon letters out of it

Tags: ruby, string, compare

I have to create a program which takes user inputs for two words, and extract unique letters from both.

eg: two words are "extrapolation" and  "among"

after removing the common alphabets result should be "extrpolatimg" regardless of the order of words fed. As in although there are two 'a's in extrapolation only one is removed..

Code written by me till now as under

```
puts "Enter the first_word : "

word_1 = gets.chomp.downcase.split('', 0)


puts "Enter second word name: "

word_2 = gets.chomp.downcase.split('', 0)

p word_1

p word_2

differences = word_1- word_2

p differences

#input1 = among
#input2 = extrapolation

# output => ["m","g"]
```

The code ignores letters in the second word which are not there in first.

Are there any built in string methods to handle this issue?

Thanks in advance for helping out..

Comment: In your example, `'a'` and `'o'` appear in both words so you removed the first `'a'` and the second `'o'` in each word. What is the rule for determining which character in each word to remove when the character appears more than once? What if the words were `'Extrapolation'` and `'Heathen'`?

Comment: Hi.. thanks for helping out.. there is no order of removing the letters.. it’s just that the matched letter has to be removed in both words once.. .. if there is one o in among and two in extrapolation.. only one ‘o’ will be removed from each of the word on match.. the second ‘o’ will remain.. any order will do…

Comment: You need to clarify in the question that if one instance of a letter is to be removed from a string it can be any instance of that letter, or specify which instance is to be removed, namely, the first or the last. It is confusing for the desired result in your example to have the first `'a'` but last `'o'` removed without stating the rule that gives that result. You didn't answer the second part of my question that involves capital letters. Perhaps you could simplify by stating that all characters are lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we are given two words.

```
w1 = "extrapolation"
w2 = "among"
```

*Step 1: Convert each of these strings to an array of characters*

```
a1 = w1.chars
  #=> ["e", "x", "t", "r", "a", "p", "o", "l", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"]
a2 = w2.chars
  #=> ["a", "m", "o", "n", "g"]
```

*Step 2: Create a hash for each array that gives the index of the first instance of each unique character in the array*

```
def first_char_pos(a)
  a.each_with_index.with_object({}) do |(c,i),h|
    h[c] = i unless h.key?(c)
  end
end
```

```
h1 = first_char_pos(a1)
  #=> {"e"=>0, "x"=>1, "t"=>2, "r"=>3, "a"=>4,
  #    "p"=>5, "o"=>6, "l"=>7, "i"=>10, "n"=>12}
h2 = first_char_pos(a2)
  #=>{"a"=>0, "m"=>1, "o"=>2, "n"=>3, "g"=>4}
```

*Step 3: Identify the letters to be removed from each word*

```
letters_to_remove = a1 & a2
  #=> ["a", "o", "n"]
```

*Step 4: Identify the indices of the letters in each word to keep*

```
def indices_to_keep(a, h, letters_to_remove)
  a.size.times.to_a - h.values_at(*letters_to_remove)
end
```

```
idx1 = indices_to_keep(a1, h1, letters_to_remove)
  #=>[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
idx2 = indices_to_keep(a2, h2, letters_to_remove)
  #=> [1, 4]
```

*Step 5: Identify, in order, the letters in each word to keep*

```
s1 = a1.values_at(*idx1)
  #=> ["e", "x", "t", "r", "p", "l", "a", "t", "i", "o"]
s2 = a2.values_at(*idx2)
  #=> ["m", "g"]
```

*Step 6: Form the desired string*

```
s1.join + s2.join
  #=> "extrplatiomg"
```

This differs from the desired string, which is `"extrpolatimg"`. The reason is that I removed the first instance of each letter to be removed whereas the desired string is obtained by removing the first `"a"` of each string and the last `"o"` of each string. Either the OP made a mistake when giving the desired result or I do not understand the rule for determining which instance of a letter is to be removed.

I have not addressed the situation where capital letters may be present  because I do not know the rules that apply in that situation.

Comment: Hello.. works like a charm.. the order of removal was not important. I believe i made a mistake in the order when giving the result..and yes all characters are in lowercase..  Thank you so much for helping out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-sub) to replace the first occurrence of a pattern: (which can be a single character)

```
'extrapolation'.sub('a', '_')
#=> "extr_polation"
```

You can also *remove* the first occurrence by passing an empty string as the replacement:

```
'extrapolation'.sub('a', '')
#=> "extrpolation"
```

This can be used in a loop to replace all characters in one string from another string:

```
input1 = 'among'
input2 = 'extrapolation'

result = input1

input2.each_char do |char|
  result = result.sub(char, '')
end

result
#=> "mg"
```

To avoid creating a new string on each iteration, you can repeatedly call [`sub!`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-sub-21) on the string, which modifies the receiver in-place. However, due to this modification, you have to [`dup`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-dup) the input to avoid modifying `input1`:

```
result = input1.dup

input2.each_char do |char|
  result.sub!(char, '')
end

result
#=> "mg"
```

This can be refactored further by utilizing [`with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) which is especially useful for providing an implicit return value inside a method:

```
def word_diff(string1, string2)
  string2.each_char.with_object(string1.dup) do |char, string|
    string.sub!(char, '')
  end
end

diff1 = word_diff(input2, input1)
#=> "extrplatio"

diff2 = word_diff(input1, input2)
#=> "mg"

diff1 + diff2
#=> "extrplatiomg"
```

Not that performance-wise, this approach might not be suitable for (very) large strings, as it will traverse the first string once for each character in the second string (or vice-versa when given the other way round).

Answer (score 1):

For the task at hand , you could take a swing at it by slightly changing your approach. Ruby, being as awesome as it is, allows us to convert strings into character arrays using the chars method. So, you can replace your split('', 0) with chars.

The logic here is to first create a copy of the second word's characters. Then , iterate over the first word's characters. If a character is found in the copy of the second word, remove it from both the first word and the copy of the second word. Whatever remains in both the words are the unique characters.

Let's turn that into code:

```
puts "Enter the first word: "
word_1 = gets.chomp.downcase.chars

puts "Enter the second word: "
word_2 = gets.chomp.downcase.chars

copy_word_2 = word_2.dup # Create a copy of word_2 characters

word_1.each do |char|
  if copy_word_2.include?(char)
    word_1.delete_at(word_1.index(char))
    copy_word_2.delete_at(copy_word_2.index(char))
  end
end

differences = word_1 + copy_word_2 # Combine remaining unique characters from both words

puts "The unique characters are: "
p differences
```

In this code , we make use of the delete_at method to remove a character at a specific index in an array, and index method to find the index of the first occurrence of the character. include? method checks if the array contains a certain character.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for this.. I never thought of making a copy.. quick question.. when we change the order of words.. say "among" first and "extrapolation" second.. the answer is different..  character "n" does not get cancelled / removed..

Comment: Does word_2 need to be duplicated? .. If so why? I am getting the same results if word_2 is used in place of copy_word_2..

Comment: For the example in the question this results in `"extrplatiomg"`, whereas the desired string is `"extrpolatimg"`. If your answer is wrong, however, so is mine, as we got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
puts 'Enter the first_word:'
chars1 = gets.chomp.downcase.chars

puts 'Enter second word name:'
chars2 = gets.chomp.downcase.chars

((chars1 - chars2) + (chars2 - chars1)).join

# with 'extrapolation' and 'amoug'
# => "extrpltimg"

# with 'amoug' and 'extrapolation'
# => "mgextrplti"
```

Comment: hi.. thanks for this.. but the answer is still not matching.. there are two 'a' in extrapolation and one 'a' in among.. your solution removes both 'a's.  The answer has to be "extrpolatimg"  regardless of the sequence of how we enter the words "among" , "extrapolation".  In other words it checks the second word if the character is there and if yes removes the one instance of the character from both words.. I hope i am clear..